# How to create a dependency for a custom gradle task?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, task

I want to execute a shell command that requires a particular jar (eg `someJar.jar`) from a particular library (eg `someGroup:someName:someVersion`) that is not used by the rest of the project, but I can't figure out how to specify the dependency for the task.

In my `build.gradle`, I have tried many variations of:

```
task salesforce(type: Exec, variousProperties: ???) { 
    executable "sh"
    args "java", "-jar", "someJar.jar"
}
```

and other properties without success.

The task should download the dependency when run.

What's the cleanest way to specify the dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
configurations {
   cp 
}

dependencies {
   cp 'some:dependency:1.0'
}

task salesforce(type: JavaExec) { 
    classpath configurations.cp
    main 'MainClass'
}
```

Comment: I ended up arriving at this myself too. Interestingly, I couldn't find a way to execute an executable jar - I had to inspect `MANIFEST.MF` and copy-paste the main class from there to the task's `main` attribute